# Set attribute safe for related model in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I need to set an attribute as safe for a related model. I use a search model with a translation relation. And there I want to set the title attribute as safe.

The problem is that the title attribute is required in the related ArticleTranslation model.

I use the yii2-translatable behavior from creocoder.

```
class ArticleSearch extends Article
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'user_id', 'status', 'category_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['title', 'summary', 'content'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
       // $this->detachBehaviors();
        $query = Article::find();
        $query->joinWith(['translations']);
        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);



        if ($this->load($params) && !$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
           return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'category_id' => $this->category_id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'article_translation.title', $this->title])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'article_translation.summary', $this->summary])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'content', $this->content]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use the  title attribute for search a related  model  based  on relation in the joined  model you should declare the proper public var for allow the use in search model (and declare this $title safe too)  eg:

```
class ArticleSearch extends Article
{

    public $title;

    public function rules()
    {
       return [
          [['id', 'user_id', 'status', 'category_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
          [['title', 'summary', 'content'], 'safe'],
       ];
   }
    ....
```